# Can the value of one select box change the value of/what is default in another checkbox and make it disabled?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 2 select boxes, "#Country" and "#StateAbbreviation" if a user selects a country other than USA - .val="USA"  in the #Country select box, I need to change the value in "#StateAbbreviation" to OTHER/INTL. - val="IT" and make it disabled.

Why doesn't this work?

```
$("#Country").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() != 'USA') {
    $("#StateAbbreviation").val() == 'IT'.attr("disbled", true);   
  }
});
```

Kane Leins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it a bit, like this:

```
$("#Country").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() != 'USA') {
    $("#StateAbbreviation").val('IT').attr("disabled", true);   
  } else {
    $("#StateAbbreviation").val('').attr("disabled", false); 
  }
});
```

When setting a value, the call is [`.val(newValue)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), otherwise you're trying to set a function to a string, and call a function that doesn't exist on a string...causing a few errors.

This also resets the `#StateAbbreviation` `<select>` and re-enables if it *is* "USA".

Comment: the `else` portion of that `if` should be `$("#StateAbbreviation").removeAttr('disabled').val('');`

Comment: @gnarf - totally forgot that half of the operation, thanks! and updated :)

Comment: Seems to work fine, thanks guys. How would I make it so that if it's not USA or CAN?? IE

$("#Country").change(function() {
  if($(this).val() != 'USA' || 'CAN') {
    $("#StateAbbreviation").val('IT').attr("disabled", true);   
  } else {
    $("#StateAbbreviation").val('SS').attr("disabled", false); 
  }
});

do I need to make USA and CAN an array and check against that array?

Comment: @Nick - how would you check it against an array var FOO = new Array = ("USA","CAN")?

Comment: @Dirty - In the link in my last comment, just replace the in-line `['USA', 'CAN']` with `FOO` or whatever the array's called.

Comment: @Nick -   
It works, thanks. Unfortunately it's clashing with another validator rule, I need to modify this $.validator.addMethod( "ReutersNA", function(value, element) { var selectedCountry = $("#Country").val(); var NorthAmerica = new Array("USA","CAN","MEX"); if($.inArray(selectedCountry,NorthAmerica) > -1) { return true; } else return false; }, "Cannot select Reuters News outside of North America." ); so it only fires if "IQPRE and or IQBAS" is checked, when I use what you did, it returns the error for the above. what a mess!

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - just FYI `new Array("USA", "CAN", "MEX")` is the same as `["USA", "CAN", "MEX"]` -- might as well save some keystrokes...